# contact form php display on email format query

Tags: php, html, forms, contacts

This is PHP code.
When email displays on email-id the content should be on next line.

```
$ToEmail = 'abc@gmail.com'; 
$EmailSubject = 'Exza Contact Form'; 
$mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
$mailheader .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
$mailheader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY = "Name :".$_POST["name"]."\n"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Email :".$_POST["email"]."\n"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Subject : ".$_POST["subject"]."\n"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Message : ".nl2br($_POST["message"])."\n"; 
mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die ("Failure");
```

Example:

> Name : Abc 
>   Email : abcd@gmail.com 
>   Subject : Any 
>   Message : All the work

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "When email displays on email-id the content should be on next line" please?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a "developer for hire" site, you need to ask a specific question if we are to help you.

Comment: I want to display user data on different line

Answer (score 0):

Just use `\r\n` instead of `\n`.

```
$ToEmail = 'abc@gmail.com'; 
$EmailSubject = 'Exza Contact Form'; 
$mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
$mailheader .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
$mailheader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY = "Name :".$_POST["name"]."\r\n"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Email :".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Subject : ".$_POST["subject"]."\r\n"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Message : ".nl2br($_POST["message"])."\r\n"; 
mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die ("Failure");
```